# AmCharts Negative Base Line Trend

Tags: javascript, charts, gradient, formula, amcharts

Within a AmCharts Line Chart (Javascript) there is a setting to change the colour of the line to be different when it is negative as opposed to it being positive.  Quite handy.

There is also a setting to change the base negative value from 0 to something else, say -20 or 150.

What I have is 2 line graphs, one a target line (straight gradient of 1:4) and the other is output production.

Does anyone know if there is a way to have the negativeBase value be something other than a flat number? say a formula or something like that?  I would like the product line to change colour depending if it is above or below the target gradient line.

Sorry no current JS Fiddle as the production data is for a private firm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible (I am the author of amCharts). I would suggest creating two lines, one above another. One could have full data and another one, which is above, only the data which needs to be in a different color.

Comment: Thanks zeroin.  I eventually did this and it works without problems.  It's good to know I wasn't spending too much time chasing unicorns :)

Comment: By the way, since v3 of amCharts you can change line color or make it dashed at any data point, here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/7kFAK/

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
var var1=somevalue;
var var2=someothervalue;
```

now you can use formula in the negative base

```
 "negativeBase": var1*var2,
```